# What is the sequence of events that happens when I'm using set() in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My code below attempts to insert a `Timestamp` into Firebase. The `Timestamp` I'm referring to is [this one here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#toDate). I plan to retrieve the inserted `Timestamp` and convert said `Timestamp` to a `Date` JS Object to be displayed when a user requests for said time. I tried retrieving said `Timestamp` and encountered something rather strange to me.

I have the following code, initially:

```js
let newRef = firebase.database().ref().child('fs').push(); //'fs' here is one of the nodes in my Firebase

newRef.set({
  //Set some other data
  timeCreated: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
}).then(() => {
  console.log('Insert successful');
});

newRef.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.val().timeCreated);
  console.log(new Date(snapshot.val().timeCreated));
});
```

I soon noticed that I was breaking my chain of `Promise`. Because of that, I changed it into the following:

```js
let newRef = firebase.database().ref().child('fs').push();

newRef.set({
  //Some other data
  timeCreated: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
}).then(() => {
  console.log('Insert successful');
  return newRef.once('value').then((snapshot) => snapshot.val().timeCreated);
}).then((timeRetrieved) => {
  console.log(timeRetrieved);
  console.log(new Date(timeRetrieved);
});
```

And it retrieved the correct data.

My confusion is at the initial code. Why does Firebase still somehow successfully retrieved `timeCreated` when the process of `set()` hasn't been completed? I looked at the `console.log(...)` and the first one to appear is the reading data process. However, as Firebase hasn't even set the value of `timeCreated`, shouldn't I be reading a `null` or some other `null`-like value? Instead, the reading data code returned a `Timestamp` that is slightly smaller in value to the `Timestamp` that is to be `set()`.

**EDIT**

As per request, these are the results I get using my initial code:

[image: Result]

However, the value of `timeCreated` stored in my Firebase is: `1556862732784`, which is different from the result of the image above (the result of the image above is the result of `console.log(snapshot.val().timeCreated)` [`1556862732273`]).

Answer (score 1):

When you execute this code:

```
let newRef = firebase.database().ref().child('fs').push(); //'fs' here is one of the nodes in my Firebase

newRef.set({
 //Set some other data
timeCreated: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
}).then(() => {
console.log('Insert successful');
});

newRef.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
 console.log(new Date(snapshot.val().timeCreated));
});
```

You will get the execution of logs in the following order:

> `console.log(new Date(snapshot.val().timeCreated));`
>
> `console.log('Insert successful');`

and that's because `set()` is asynchronous, so the code after it will be executed before the data is even retrieved.

---

> Instead, the reading data code returned a Timestamp that is slightly smaller in value to the Timestamp that is to be  `set()`.

Since you created a new `Date()` in the `console.log()`, then you probably got the following time.

```js
console.log(new Date(null));
```

Comment: Hello, I apologise for the late response. I've included `timeCreated` value and as you can see, it is not `null` as I expected.

Comment: I've also added a `console.log(snapshot.val().createdAt)` to display the stringified `Timestamp` retrieved. Also, what do you mean by *and that's because `set()` is asynchronous, so the code after it will be executed before the data is even retrieved*? Isn't `once()` asynchronous too? And did you mean *before the data is even set*?

Comment: Sorry to bother. But could you please take a look at my new update?